Expo EAS googleSignin developer error code 10
I am building Authenticate with Firebase and Google for Expo EAS React Native App
I wanted to add googleSignin option using react-native-google-signin library.
I followed all the setups for firebase and google cloud.
I used credintials.json for local credintials when building the app,
I used the SHA1 and SHA256 from this keystore on both firebase and google play console,
I made sure that the SHA1 fingerprint certificate is set for my firebase project fingerprint and as Upload key certificate for google play console.
as for google cloud the OAuth 2.0 Client ID was auto created by firebase when I enabled Google in authentication > Sign-in method in firebase,
the OAuth 2.0 Client ID is set as Web client ( web application ) and didn't ask for fingerprint.
I put "plugins": ["@react-native-google-signin/google-signin"]
in app.json
and in android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.9.23'

        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = '21.2.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

for android/app/build.gradle :
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.3.0')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.5.0')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.5.0')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.1.0')
    ...
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


on frontend:
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId:
    "MYCLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
});

// MYCLIENTID is from firebase, which auto created on google cloud

my problem is that I get this error on frontend:
{
  nativeStackAndroid: [
    {
      lineNumber: 3,
      file: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0',
      methodName: 'fromStatus',
      class: 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 3,
      file: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@21.2.0',
      methodName: 'getSignedInAccountFromIntent',
      class: 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 217,
      file: 'RNGoogleSigninModule.java',
      methodName: 'onActivityResult',
      class: 'com.reactnativegooglesignin.RNGoogleSigninModule$RNGoogleSigninActivityEventListener'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 393,
      file: 'ReactContext.java',
      methodName: 'onActivityResult',
      class: 'com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 824,
      file: 'ReactInstanceManager.java',
      methodName: 'onActivityResult',
      class: 'com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 187,
      file: 'ReactDelegate.java',
      methodName: 'onActivityResult',
      class: 'com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 151,
      file: 'ReactActivityDelegate.java',
      methodName: 'onActivityResult',
      class: 'com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 241,
      file: 'ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt',
      methodName: 'onActivityResult',
      class: 'expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 75,
      file: 'ReactActivity.java',
      methodName: 'onActivityResult',
      class: 'com.facebook.react.ReactActivity'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 9362,
      file: 'Activity.java',
      methodName: 'dispatchActivityResult',
      class: 'android.app.Activity'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 6056,
      file: 'ActivityThread.java',
      methodName: 'deliverResults',
      class: 'android.app.ActivityThread'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 6102,
      file: 'ActivityThread.java',
      methodName: 'handleSendResult',
      class: 'android.app.ActivityThread'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 67,
      file: 'ActivityResultItem.java',
      methodName: 'execute',
      class: 'android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 45,
      file: 'ActivityTransactionItem.java',
      methodName: 'execute',
      class: 'android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 139,
      file: 'TransactionExecutor.java',
      methodName: 'executeCallbacks',
      class: 'android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 96,
      file: 'TransactionExecutor.java',
      methodName: 'execute',
      class: 'android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 2685,
      file: 'ActivityThread.java',
      methodName: 'handleMessage',
      class: 'android.app.ActivityThread$H'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 106,
      file: 'Handler.java',
      methodName: 'dispatchMessage',
      class: 'android.os.Handler'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 230,
      file: 'Looper.java',
      methodName: 'loopOnce',
      class: 'android.os.Looper'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 319,
      file: 'Looper.java',
      methodName: 'loop',
      class: 'android.os.Looper'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 8919,
      file: 'ActivityThread.java',
      methodName: 'main',
      class: 'android.app.ActivityThread'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: -2,
      file: 'Method.java',
      methodName: 'invoke',
      class: 'java.lang.reflect.Method'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 578,
      file: 'RuntimeInit.java',
      methodName: 'run',
      class: 'com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller'
    },
    {
      lineNumber: 1103,
      file: 'ZygoteInit.java',
      methodName: 'main',
      class: 'com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit'
    }
  ],
  userInfo: null,
  message: 'DEVELOPER_ERROR',
  code: '10'
}

when I test the app on the development build, I don't get this error,
I only get it when I try to test the production build which is available on Google Play Store.
am I missing something here?
how can I fix this?
Thank you in advance for any little help.
What I tried so far:

I used EAS credentials to make keystore, I used the SHA1 form this one for Google Play Console Upload Certificate and I used it as Firestore fingerprint.

I made two different keystores in EAS credentials, one for Firebase and one for Upload certificate,

I made sure that the package name is the same everywhere.

I added 3 SHA1 fingerprints in Firebase : App Signing SHA1 from Google Play Console, Release SHA1 from eas credentials, and debug SHA1 from ./Android/app/debug.keystore


I still get the same error (Developer Error Code 10)

I had the same error and just resolved one minute ago.
I solved it by following the official troubleshoot guide for this error: https://react-native-google-signin.github.io/docs/troubleshooting

This is always (always!) a configuration mismatch between your app and
the server-side setup (in Firebase or Google Cloud console).

To sum up, I used the wrong SHA-1.
To get the SHA-1  ./gradlew signingReport in root of /android folder.
The output will contain multiple SHA-1. You must take the first. The one at the TOP of the output. My mistake was that I took the last.
(If you have no /android folder you can generate it with npx expo prebuild command)
EDIT: Sorry, I just noticed you get the error in production. But I think the troubleshoot guide can apply for you.

Not working, I made sure that SHA1 in eas credentials keystore is the same for Firebase fingerprint SHA1, and another Keystore for google play upload certificate. that didn't work, I also tried to use the same SHA1 in my default eas credentials keystore for both Firebase and google play upload certificate, the package name is the same everywhere, all that didn't work, I still get developer error code 10 which means SHA1 mismatch I don't know how. I tried following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY3O_wrvDsI but didn't work either
